# Translation operators and correct vocabulary

Tags: linear-transformations

I am trying to find the correct vocabulary to describe a distinction between two operations.  The first is the simple translation operator, that when it acts upon a function $f(x)$ shifts the argument:
$$
{\cal T}(a)  f(x)=f(x+a)
$$ This is a linear operator.
The second might be called a ``shift" operator that acts upon a vector, $\vec x$.
$$
{\cal S}(\vec b)  \vec x = \vec x + \vec b.
$$
This is distinct from the above because while
$$
{\cal T}(a) (f(x)+g(x)) =f(x+a) + g(x+a)
$$
The shift operator does not work that way:
$$
{\cal S}(\vec b)  \vec x + {\cal S}(\vec b) \vec y =( \vec x + \vec b) + (\vec y + \vec b) = \vec x + \vec y + 2 \vec b \neq (\vec x + \vec y + \vec b)= {\cal S}(\vec b)(\vec x+ \vec y). 
$$
Therefore this second operator is not a linear operator.

The problem is that many of my students have had both things called "translations" and superficially they look the same.  I want to use the proper terminology (and perhaps clarifying terminology!) that will make the distinction clear.

Comment: This reminds me of active/passive transformations used in physics. Have seen them in Wikipedia also.

Comment: The vector transformation is called an affine transformation

Comment: Translations are not linear since they don't fix the origin. I think that's a good reason to have the affine case called translations.